# Is it possible to tell Git to only use rebase=true when pulling from its upstream?

Tags: git

In this project we have defined the following policy:

1. Pull of a branch from its upstream must use "rebase"
2. Integrating changes from a branch to another branch must use "merge"

The idea is that we want to avoid to pollute the history with automatic merge commits during pull, but keep the history intact when synchronizing different branches.

I have this configuration in .gitconfig:

```
[branch]
    autosetuprebase = always

[branch "feature/XYZ"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/feature/XYZ
    rebase = true
```

If I do (assuming my current branch is XYZ):

```
git pull
```

everything is fine, it performs a fetch followed by a rebase.

However, if someone does:

```
git pull origin master
```

to update the branch XYZ with changes in master, git will also do a rebase.

The question: is there a way to either block the pull when the upstream branch is not the one configured in the .gitconfig OR to not use the rebase in this case?